# Notation for limit in category theory

Tags: category-theory, notation, limits-colimits

Really quite a silly question, but I'm confused about the notation around limits in category theory. Given a diagram of shape $I$, say $F$, I would write the limit of $F$ in some category as $\operatorname{lim}_{I}F$. But recently I saw someone write $\operatorname{lim}_{i \in I} F(i)$.

Something like $Hom_C(-,\operatorname{lim}_{i \in I}F(i)) \cong \operatorname{lim}_{i\in I} Hom_{C}(-,F(i))$ was stated ( the claim being that the Yoneda functor preserves limits).

Does this mean the same thing as $\operatorname{lim}_{I}F$? So in this case does this mean,

$Hom_C(-,\operatorname{lim}_{I}F) \cong \operatorname{lim}_{I} Hom_{C}(-,F)$?

Since $F(i)$s are objects and not functors, I'm not sure what else this could mean.Thanks!

Comment: It's just notation. Don't bother reading too much into it.

Comment: Oh so it does just mean the same thing?

Comment: the same thing yes

Comment: This is like when one writes "$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(x^2+y^2)}dxdy$" instead of "$\int_{\mathbb R^2} f$, where $f \colon \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is defined by $f(x,y)=e^{-(x^2+y^2)}$".